# how to pass object parameters in hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

as show below, I pass a parameter *list* to an useFunction; In useGetName function, I need control params "data" as "item"  for some reason。It turns out that circulate update。

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setFilter([{ value: "" }]);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }, []);

  const list = [
    {
      name: "a",
      value: filter
    }
  ];

  return <div>{useGetName(list)}</div>;
}

function useGetName(data) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(data);

   useEffect(() => {
    // for some reason, I need control params "data" as "item"
    console.log("data", data);
    setItem(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("item", item);
      }}
    >
      click me
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the way I have fixed like that:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data", data);
    setItem(data);
  }, [JSON.stringify(data)]);  // JSON.stringify
```

how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! `useGetName` doesn't make much sense to me. For one, dumping props into state is an antipattern, and for two, the `useEffect` doesn't appear to be doing anything asynchronous that would necessitate its existence. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve with this code? Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of the whole dumping props into a useState hook issue, which is unnecessary, passing an object to a custom hook and watching said object with a useEffect hook does seem to cause an infinite loop. Thinking about offering a bounty.